# JavaScript/JQuery radio button with just text

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to make an RSVP form with CSS/HTML/JS and populating it with PHP, I'm trying to make a radio button selection with just text. The two options are to Accept [X] and Decline [] with the radio changing the X between the brackets([]). I'm having trouble getting it working with multiple radio buttons because of the ids. Does anyone have any suggestions?

End result would be Accept [X] and Decline [], when accepted and Accept [] and Decline [X] when the decline is accepted for each radio.

```js
document.body.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
  let target = e.target;
  switch (target.id) {
    case 'accept':
        break;
    case 'decline':
        break;
  }
});
```

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid 2px red;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
  border: solid 2px green;
  content: attr(decline)"TEST";
}
```

```html
Nick:
<input type="radio" id="accept1" name="nick" checked>
<label for="accept1">Accept [X]</label>


<input type="radio" id="decline1" name="nick">
<label for="decline1">Decline []</label>

<br>

Joe:
<input type="radio" id="accept2" name="joe" checked>
<label for="accept2">Accept [X]</label>


<input type="radio" id="decline2" name="joe">
<label for="decline2">Decline []</label>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove the `[X]` and `[]` from label ... then add

```
input[type="radio"]:checked + label:after {
  content: " [X]";
}
input[type="radio"] + label:after {
  content: " []";
}
```

to the CSS

... also, whatever `content: attr(decline)"TEST";` is, it does nothing - remove it

Result:

```js
document.body.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
            let target = e.target;
            switch (target.id) {
                case 'accept':
                    break;
                case 'decline':
                    break;
            }
        });
```

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid 2px red;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
  border: solid 2px green;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label:after {
  content: " [X]";
}
input[type="radio"] + label:after {
  content: " [ ]";
}
```

```html
Nick:
<input type="radio" id="accept1" name="nick" checked>
<label for="accept1">Accept</label>


<input type="radio" id="decline1" name="nick">
<label for="decline1">Decline</label>

<br>

Joe:
<input type="radio" id="accept2" name="joe" checked>
<label for="accept2">Accept</label>


<input type="radio" id="decline2" name="joe">
<label for="decline2">Decline</label>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I was trying different ways to do it that's why there is "content: attr(decline)"TEST";".